# Chrome runs extremely slowly when plugins are enabled, thick black bar under recent history

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

[image: black bar in chrome]

Hopefully someone can help, I've uninstalled and reinstalled chrome, run the cleanup tool and cleared the cache, all the usual suspects.

A few weeks ago chrome started hanging, I disabled all of my extensions and it ran fine. I tried to isolate the problem extension but any extension seems to cause it to start hanging, not just a specific one.

Now I've started to see this thick black bar under my recent history, has anyone got any ideas what's going on and how I can fix it? I'm on the latest 45.0.2454.85 m on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Do you sign in with an account on your chrome, maybe the problem is related with an extension that your account bring back even after you make a clean install

Comment: I don't this is my work pc so I keep it separate from my personal chrome profile

Comment: than you can try uninstall chrome and than delete this folder: C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Local\Google  , and than try again an fresh install without singing in with any account

Comment: Tried it but no luck, bar is still there

Comment: have you tried this: https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/

Comment: yes first thing I tried

Comment: try to install an older version of chrome or change it to 32 or 64bit version of it just for change

Comment: Try to check your system with antivirus, and if your hardware/software can handle all the plugins you enabled.

Comment: Hi emirjonb as I found it was actually a chrome regression but I need to award this bounty and your comments were the most helpful, would you like to post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this is a known regression in the latest chrome, I don't know why everyone isn't seeing it

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=508717

Thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is your work PC, you may need to sync your settings when you sign in and as the person who replied had said, it might be something that is attached to the account.

Comment: I didn't log in to any service on a fresh account and it still appears after reinstall and deleting appcache folder

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure I uninstalled, deleted appcache google folderand deleted the program files folder. My profile doesn't exist, my bookmarks are gone, my extensions are gone but the black bar is still there.

Answer (score 0):

check whether your RAM is sufficient to satisfy chrome. May be RAM extension is needed for stopping hanging chrome.

Comment: Thanks but I've found the issue is a chrome bug, there was no change in ram or usage when this started